# Mulitthreading problem with BeginInvoke, EndInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, begininvoke

I have a client application, that displays realtime values. The values are provided through a DDE-Advise. These realtime values are moving axis of a cnc-machine. So there are about 100 advises **per minute** comming in through this `DdeClientAdvise`-Method.
When the application is getting many DDE-Advises it seems that suddenly all adivses are lost.
I reduced the problem to the following:

```
public class NcddeZugriff
{
  private DdeClient _ddeClient; //see http://ndde.codeplex.com/

  public NcDdeZugriff()
  {
    _ddeClient = new DdeClient("ncdde", "machineswitch");
    _ddeClient.Connect();
    _ddeClient.Advise += DdeClientAdvise;
  }

  private delegate void CallbackDelegate(object sender, DdeAdviseEventArgs e);    

  private void DdeClientAdvise(object sender, DdeAdviseEventArgs e)
  {
    CallbackDelegate callbackDelegate = DdeClientAdviseCallback;
    _logging.InfoFormat("Advise-Callback for {0}", e.Item);
    //LINE A : return;

    callbackDelegate.BeginInvoke(sender, e, callbackDelegate.EndInvoke, null);
  }

  private void DdeClientAdviseCallback(object sender, DdeAdviseEventArgs e)
  {
    _logging.InfoFormat("Asynchron for {0}", e.Item);
    //do some work with e.Text...
  }
}
```

If I remove comment LINE A, everything works fine, no advise got lost. All the advises are being logged.
If I enable the BeginInvoke, after awhile the `DdeClientAdvise`-Method is not being called anymore, no more log-entries.

What am I doing wrong with BeginInvoke, EndInvoke?

Edit: Add some more Information about the class.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, speed up advise processing by moving out logging into the separate thread?

Comment: DdeClientAdvise function is on top of the stack of the code provided, who is the caller of DdeClientAdvise function ?

Comment: Odds are good that a delegate is getting garbage collected with code like this.  Impossible to see which one from the snippet.  Test this theory by using GC.Collect() to force the GC early.  Repair by storing the delegate instance in a field of the class.

Comment: @Tigran: The `DdeClient`-Class subscribes to a DDE-Server. The method `DdeClientAdvise`is a callback for the `Advise`-Event of the `DdeClient`-Class.

Comment: @sll: In the seperate thread is another thread invoked, depending on the e.item. But this has currently no influence to the problem. Because right now the code is just like above.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Are you talking about the `CallbackDelegate`?  So I would use a field like `private CallbackDelegate _callbackDelegate;` But I would like to have invoked a new delegate for each DDE advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like @Hans Passant was right: the delegate was getting garbage collected. Storing the delegate in a field seems to solve the issue.
Although I changed the design of the whole project. So I can't say for sure, that this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

don't you have to call `EndInvoke` inside DdeClientAdviseCallback?